# Immunity Debugger reset windows to default tiling

Tags: immunity-debugger

I have changed the windows from the original tiling layout in Immunity Debugger. I would like to restore the original tiling. I have tried restarting the program but the modified tiling remains. Is there a procedure for restoring the original tiling?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what you mean with "original tiling". As far as I know Immunity just displays the `CPU` window initially. All the other windows are normally closed. So I would recommend to just close all windows and open `View`>`CPU`.

---

To "reset" the tiling within the `CPU` window. Just close all windows expect the `CPU` window. Minimize the `CPU` window manually and click `Tile horizontal` afterwards. Normally the tiling within the `CPU` window should be centered now.

---

In the case you want to display multiple windows and re-arrange them:

1. close all windows
2. open the windows of interest with `View`>`CPU` / `Memory` / `Log`/ `...`
3. Tile windows with: `Window` > `Tile horizontal / vertical`

Until now, I didn't find a better solution.

Comment: When you reopen CPU it is not maximized so it is easy to miss that it has the 4-way default layout (disassembly, registers, memdump and stack) inside that single panel, so this answer is clearly the correct way to go.

Answer (score 4):

The default is CPU main thread which has four panels, three of which may become hidden if you have closed it or clicked on additional windows. To get back the initial layout, close all windows, reopen with CPU Main thread and resize the edges to reveal the heap, the register panels etc.